# Lubuntu Clock Gone

Tags: lubuntu, 16.10

I was just exploring my new Lubuntu installation & accidentally switched off the clock...so I cant see it. How do i get it back please?

What do I need to do to be able to view the clock?

Comment: tried a reboot?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the panel by right clicking it and clicking preferences, then to applets. Click add, find the clock, and add it. That should work, but comment if it doesn't.

Edit: DK Boses solutions works well, and is simpler, see comments.

Comment: When you right-click on the lxpanel, you may *first* have to click on `Add / Remove Panel Items` and *then* click on `Panel Preferences`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou for the detailed reply, but I have followed the steps carefully, as written by DK Bose, but when I click on Panel Preferences, there is no Add Clock in the list displayed.
What can you suggest that I am doing wrong?

Regards,

James